# Keys that I press before encountering a cin get written immediately when cin is encountered

Tags: c++

I have this bit of code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    return 0;
}
```

In the time the program was sleeping I pressed some keys. This is what i see after those 5 seconds have passed and the cin is encountered.

[image]

Any ideas on why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Input is buffered by the terminal driver.

Comment: How do I clear it?

Comment: You have to use OS-specific mechanisms, I don't think C++ has anything to deal with this.

Comment: You can read from cin, discard the input, until cin is empty.